# usercontrols with variably named elements

Tags: asp.net, html

I've been reading about user controls on msdn, and I was wondering how does one deal with element IDs that may be variable?

For example, say I have usercontrol1.ascx on my page that contains this:

```
<div id="myPageDiv1">
     <div id="container1">
         Contents
     </div>
</div>
```

What if I need the IDs to be different across different pages?

Maybe I need another page that needs to look like this:

```
    <div id="myPageDiv2">
     <div id="container3">
         Contents 
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a property to your usercontrol so you can change it on a page-by-page basic:

**UserControl**

```
Public Property SomeDivID as String
```

**ASPX**

```
<div id="<%= Me.SomeDivID %>">

</div>
```

**Page**

```
<control:yourusercontrol SomeDivID="myPageDiv1" runat="server" />

<control:yourusercontrol SomeDivID="myPageDiv2" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a property in your user control.

```
Public Property DivName As String
```

You can set it in your codebehind to your desired name.  You can even pass this from your controlling page.

```
DivName = "MyDesiredDivName"
```

Then you can use crocodile syntax in your markup to render the value of the property.

```
<div id="<%= Me.DivName %>">
     <div id="container1">
         Contents
     </div>
</div>
```